# Get number of rows in each section of a table in UITesting Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a tableview with 3 sections, each with 3 rows. In UITesting with Xcode 7, I am able to access cell with app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(index).

What should I do, if I want to access first row of the third section.

Please help. I'm struck with this for past three days.

Answer (score 10):

In UIAutomation there is no concept of section. The tableView will be flattened for you. This can be verified by printing `tableView.debugDescription` in the console.

So in your case with a table with 3 sections and 3 cells and if you want to access the first row of the third section, then all you need to do is:

```
app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(6)
```

Answer (score -3):

What did you mean at "section"? If it is a column, try smth like: 
     app.tables["tableId"].**tableRows**.elementBoundByIndex(0).cells.elementBoundByIndex(2)

PS This [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/ui-testing-in-xcode-7-part-1-ui-testing-gotchas/) will be usefull for you

Answer (score -4):

You can create an index first

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNumber, inSection: indexNumber)
```

Then you can modify the particular element like this

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top
```